# ajax and jquery and symfony (Long polling issue) 

Tags: jquery, ajax, long-polling

I'm trying to implement long polling in a php chat script, however the long polling puts all the ajax request i send to sleep waiting for the original one.

BTW i'm working with symfony framework.

Any idea ?

-- UPDATE --

Here is some code snippets

Javascript :

```
function whosTyping(person_id){
 $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'/chat/whoisTyping',
     data:'person_id='+person_id
     dataType:'json',
     success:function(resp){
         if(resp == 'true') $('.is_typing').show();
         else $('.is_typing').hide();
         setTimeout(function(){
             whosTyping(person_id)
         },1000)
     }
 })
}
```

PHP:

```
public function executeWhoisTyping(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->setLayout(false);
    $this->setTemplate(false);
    sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);
    $person_id = $request->getParameter('person_id');
    $target_person_id = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getPerson()->getId();
    $check = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Typing')->findByPersonIdAndTargetPersonId($person_id)->toArray();
    while(empty($check)){
        usleep(1000);
        clearstatcache();
        $check = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Typing')->findByPersonIdAndTargetPersonId($person_id)->toArray();            
    }
    Doctrine_Core::getTable('Typing')->createQuery()
            ->delete()
            ->where('target_person_id = ?', $target_person_id)
            ->execute();
    return $this->renderText(json_encode('true'));
}
```

And yes i'm trying to send regular ajax requests but the they get canceled waiting for the long polling response"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok guys i figured it out

the thing is to make it work with symfony i had to end the current session using session_write_close()

so the action function become the follwing

```
public function executeWhoisTyping(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->setLayout(false);
    $this->setTemplate(false);
    sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);
    $person_id = $request->getParameter('person_id');
    $target_person_id = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getPerson()->getId();
    $check = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Typing')->findByPersonIdAndTargetPersonId($person_id,$target_person_id)->toArray();
    while(empty($check)){
        usleep(100000);
        clearstatcache();
        session_write_close();
        $check = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Typing')->findByPersonIdAndTargetPersonId($person_id,$target_person_id)->toArray();            
    }

    return $this->renderText(json_encode(!empty($check) ? 'true' : 'false'));
}
```

hope that helps